# how to hide <f:param> parameter value on page view source

Tags: html, jsf

**1. this is .xhtml file**
there is a ...xhtml page and in that page's p:dataTable included another page i.e plandata.xhtml and in plandata.xhtml we have written:

```
< h:commandLink value="#{plan.rmsId}"
action="#{planBean.viewPlanAction}" ajax="false">
< f:param name="rmsPlanId" value="#{plan.rmsId}" />
< f:param name="planStatus" value="#{plan.planStatus}" />
< f:param name="pendingWith" value="#{plan.pendingWith}" />
< f:param name="pendingWithRole" value="#{plan.pendingWithRole}"/>
```

**and this is bean code:**

```
pendingWithVar = myRequest.getParameter("pendingWith");
if(null == pendingWithVar){
pendingWithVar = planMapping.getPendingWith();
}
plan.setPendingWith(pendingWithVar);
String pendingWithRole = myRequest.getParameter("pendingWithRole");
if(null == pendingWithRole){
pendingWithRole = ""+planMapping.getPendingWithUserRole();
}
```

I have used f:param tag with commandLink. But when right click and select view source option it shows that parameter value and i want to hide that values.Is there any solution on this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this `f:param`?

Comment: Build and pass the parameter in your backing bean instead. Where's your code?

Comment: Thanks for reply now I have provided detailed code

Comment: @Simon Arsenault- f:param is used for send that value to backbean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use `<f:attribute .../>` (it's not shown in the source).

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <f:attribute name="pendingWith" value="#{plan.pendingWith}"/>
    <f:attribute .../>
</h:commandLink>
```

To obtain the value your backing bean, you need to obtain your `UIComponent` instance (you can use the `binding` attribute of `h:commandLink` and do:

```
myUiComponent.getAttributes().get("format")
```